# how to parse a number from sql output

Tags: sql, parsing, awk

Hi I need to parse a number from sql output :

```
  COUNT(*)
----------
       924
       140
       173
       583
       940
        77

6 rows selected.
```

if the the fisrt line is less then 10 I want to create a empty file, 
The problem is I dont know how to parse it, the numbers  are still changing (from 0 to  ca. 10 000 ) .

Comment: Be more specific - exactly what output do you want?

Comment: Could really do with more detail. Do you need to do this just in SQL? I think you'd have to use an SSIS package if thats the case to create the file.  Are you reading these values into an application?  If so what type of application? What programming language?

Comment: what language should be responsible for creating the empty file? is it a bash shell script?

Answer (score 2):

Question is very unclear so I'll make some assumptions. You'll get the output above from sql either to file or stdout and you would like to test of the first line containing  digits is less than 10. Correct?

This is *one* way to do it.

```
sed -n '3p' log | awk '{ print ($1 < 10) ? "true" : "false" }'
```

- sed is used to print the 3rd line from your example
- this is then piped into awk which makes to comparison.

...or putting it together in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

while read variable;
do
    if [[ "$variable" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
        then
        break
    fi
done < input

if [ "$variable" -lt 10 ]
    then
    echo 'less than 10'
    # add your code here, eg
    # touch /path/to/file/to/be/created
fi
```